# Static property injection configuration best practice

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I have helper component used in multiple classes. This is typical scenario:

```cs
public class HelperComponent 
{
    public void HelperMethod() 
    {
        // do something
    }
}

public class MyClass 
{
    private static HelperComponent Helper{ get; set;}

    public void Method1() 
    {
        Helper.HelperMethod();
    }
}
```

usage: `new MyClass().Method1();`

I would like to know what is advised spring.net configuration/solution for this configuration? 
Initially I used this line to fetch helper component:

```cs
ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("HelperComponentName")
```

Then I read that this isn't preferable solution and that I should use injection in order to avoid dependency to spring and have transparent component usage.

My question is: how can I achieve this using spring configuration?

Can I inject static property into class? Or should I make Helper instance property? 
If I convert Helper to instance property, do I need to define MyClass in spring configuration and use CreateObject to instantiate MyClass?
If yes, it isn't satisfiable solution for me beacuse I would like to instantiate MyClass as written above.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with spring, but what you want to do is inject the dependency (through a constructor or property), make in non-static, and then manage the lifecycle through the IOC container.  Spring must have a way to set the lifecycle of HelperComponent to Singleton.

Comment: @dtryon I already done that (since I'm retrieving it with context.GetObject()). But, how can I instantiate MyClass if I set Helper to non.static? As I said, I don't want to use context.CreateObject.

Comment: The way this is usually done is that you would have a constructor in MyClass that takes a HelperComponent as a parameter and then sets a local field of the same type.  Then, you would register both classes in the container.  After that, you would resolve MyClass from the container and Spring will automatically instantiate the HelperComponent.  In this way, Spring will manage the lifecycle of the dependency.

Comment: *Best practice* for static Property Injection is to not use static Property Injection. Refactor MyClass to take an instance of HelperComponent in its constructor.

Comment: @MarkSeemann OK, just to be sure: Suppose that I refactored MyClass as proposed and marked MyClass component as prototype in configuration. If I want to create new MyClass instance explicitly I need to use context.GetObject("MyClass")?

Comment: Yeah, or even better, you could just ask the container to compose an even higher-order object that contains MyClass somewhere in the graph.

Comment: @dtryon, can you enter your comment in form of answer?

Comment: @MarkSeemann can you enter your comment in form of answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with spring, but when using an IOC container, you usually register all of your application's dependencies (and their life cycles) and then resolve the 'entry-point' object at the top of the object graph.

This allows you to take advantage of features of the IOC container like constructor and property injection.

Once you are set up like this, you can manage the individual objects life cycles through the IOC containers configuration.

In this case, I would inject `HelperComponent` in the constructor of `MyClass` after registering the `HelperComponent` as a singleton in the IOC container configuration.